# Why number are (not) representable in double precision IEEE754?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, theorem

I am confused on **IEEE754** double precision, I consider two questions:
**1.**
Why each number from interval -2<sup>54</sup>, -2<sup>54</sup>+2, -2<sup>54</sup>+4...2<sup>54</sup> is representable ?

**2.** Why 2<sup>54</sup>+2 is not representable ?

Can you help me ?  I understand way of working  **IEEE754** - however, I have a problem with *seeing* it.

Comment: Hint for question 2: How many bits are needed to represent  2^{54}+2? How many bits does the significand (mantissa) of an IEEE-754 `binary64` (double-precision number) comprise?

Comment: Note that `this style` is intended for code, not for randomly emphasizing words. And exponents can be entered with the syntax -2<sup>54</sup>.

Comment: Unfortunately "proper" exponents don't work in comments, last I checked. I wish the SE folks would finally enable MathJax for SO.

Comment: @njuffa I can see that mantisa is always $< 2$. I mean that 2^{54} has exact representation (mantisa is equals to 1.0000..0). It is not possible to set mantisa in such way that we get 2^{54} + 2, because mantisa < 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 53 bits in the significand (or mantissa) of an IEEE 754 double. −2<sup>54</sup> can be exactly represented, as

```
mantissa: 1.00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00 (bin)
exponent: 54
sign:     1
```

Now let's forget the sign bit for a moment. It is irrelevant for this explanation. So assume we have +2<sup>54</sup>.

With this exponent, the ***lowest -- rightmost -- bit of the significand*** has the value 2<sup>-52</sup> * 2<sup>54</sup> = 4. So 2<sup>54</sup> + 4 is encoded as:

```
mantissa: 1.00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 01 (bin)
exponent: 54                                                             ^
                                                                lowest bit
```

**But there is no value inbetween. So you cannot encode 2<sup>54</sup> + 2**.

Why is this not a problem for **−2<sup>54</sup> + 2**? Because that is the same as **−(2<sup>54</sup> − 2)**, and that is represented as:

```
mantissa: 1.11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11
exponent: 53 !!
sign:     1
```

And the exponent 53 means you have steps of 2<sup>-52</sup> * 2<sup>53</sup> = 2. The next value toward 0 is then:

```
mantissa: 1.11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 11111 10
exponent: 53
sign:     1
```

which is −2<sup>54</sup> + 4, or actually −(2<sup>54</sup> − 4). And you can go on like that until you reach −2<sup>53</sup>.

Comment: `2^54 - 1` is not representable in IEEE 754 binary64. Did you mean `2^53 - 1`? (Or `2^54 - 2`?) Neither is `2^54 + 2`. It looks as though your exponents are all off by one.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. When you're computing the value of the least significant bit of the significand, you want to be multiplying by 2^-52 rather than 2^-53.

Comment: Yeah, I am off by 1 exponent all the time. Amending the answer. I haven't had coffee yet. <g>

Comment: *With this exponent, the lowest -- rightmost -- bit of the significand has the value 2^{-52} * 2^{54} = 4* For me it is not true, After all we have always *1.* - I mean that it is (1+2^{-52}) * 2^{54}

Comment: I understand why 2^{52} +2 is not representable.  I don't understand why you wrote (2^{-52} * 2^54). It seems to me  that you should write ((1+2^{-52})*2^{54}). After all, each mantissa (normalized number) is > 1, however you mantissa = 2^{-52} < 1

Comment: @HaskellFun: 
 
I wrote that **the lowest bit** has the value 4, with that exponent. The entire number has of course the value `2^54 + 4`. Note that, because of the exponent of 54, it should be calculated as `mantissa * 2^54 = (1 + 2^-52) * 2^54 = 1 * 2^54 + 2^-52 * 2^-54 = 2^54 + 4 = 18014398509481988`. The lowest bit has the value `2^-52 * 2^exponent`, the second to lowest bit has the value `2^-51 * 2^exponent`, etc., all the way up to the leading bit, which has the value `2^0 * 2^exponent`. Add all these bits together (if they are set), and you have your full number.

Comment: Thanks you very much!