# Why dividing two doubles on C++ aren't showing the right result?

Tags: c++

Hello I'm having problem with dividing two doubles on C++, on a basic C++ it's working fine, for example

```
double DfirstNumber = 4.3;
double DsecondNumber = 2.0;
double DthirdNumber = DfirstNumber/DsecondNumber;
std::cout << DthirdNumber;
```

but not on the code below:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <regex>
    std::string getLastLine(std::ifstream& in)
    {
        std::string line;
        while (in >> std::ws && std::getline(in, line)) // skip empty lines
            ;

        return line;
    }

    int main()
    {
        double DfirstNumber;
        double DsecondNumber;
        while(true){
            std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\myfile.txt");

            if (file)
            {
                std::string line = getLastLine(file);
                Sleep(1000);
                try {
                    std::regex re("\\d*\\.\\d*");
                    std::sregex_iterator next(line.begin(), line.end(), re);
                    int i = 0;
                    std::string firstNumber;
                    std::string secondNumber;
                    while (i < 3) {
                        std::smatch match = *next;
                        if (i == 1) {
                            firstNumber = match.str();
                            DfirstNumber = std::stof(firstNumber);
                        }
                        if (i == 2) {
                            secondNumber = match.str();
                            DsecondNumber = std::stof(secondNumber);
                        }
                        next++;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                catch (std::regex_error&) {
                    std::cout << "regex error";
                }
                double DthirdNumber = DsecondNumber) / DfirstNumber;
                std::cout << DthirdNumber << std::endl;
            }
            else{
                std::cout << "Can't Open the file.\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting every second a new line on `myfile.txt` so I had to check the last line of file, then using regular expression to get the desired datas and store them to C++ variables.

This is how myfile.txt looks

```
Hello Name Name0.00042Surname NameSurname Name0.00042$100.03
Hello Name Name0.00143Surname NameSurname Name0.00143$100.53
Hello Name Name0.00342Surname NameSurname Name0.00342$100.32
..............................................^1stNr^.^2ndNr^
... and another program just continues to extract lines like these  every second!
```

Could anyone explain to me why is this happening, because if I'm trying to divide for example
`DfirstNumber = 407.33
 DsecondNumber = 0.015982`
I'm not getting `25486.79764735327` but I'm getting `25489.8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why number are (not) representable in double precision IEEE754?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291410/why-number-are-not-representable-in-double-precision-ieee754)

Comment: @StarShine i don't see anything that is similar here!

Comment: check if the double type can represent the number accurately, i.e start by  assigning and printing it to the console. It is possible that it simply cannot be represented with the precision you are expecting.

Comment: @StarShine yeah I tried `std::cout << DfirstNumber << " and " << DsecondNumber;`, it's showing correct, but when I try to divide them, it's showing just one digit after comma!

Comment: @StarShine also, I don't need setprecision on this case!

Comment: try printing the number itself first (as a double).

Comment: The default is `precision(6)` which gives you 6 digits. For example 5 digits before the decimal point and 1 after.